# Apply two function arguments into onClick tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, arguments

In order to print a set of data on my page framework, I create a javascript `function` to set it as `onClick` on a `a` tag. However, the function is just getting only one argument when clicking to print and not all of them.

So I've made the HTML:

```
<div id="services">Services available</div>
<div id="products">Products available</div>
```

And the javascript function (with two arguments):

```
function Popup(data1, data2) {
  var printWindow = window.open('', 'Page', 'width=600,height=600,left=400');
  printWindow.document.write(data1);
  printWindow.document.write(data2);

  return true;
}

function PrintElem(elem1, elem2) {
  Popup($(elem1, elem2).html());
}
```

And the `a` tag was set to be clicked and open a popup. The windows are opened, with the Services Available, but the Products do not appear and outputs `undefined`

```
<a onClick="PrintElem('#services, #products')">Print page</a>
```

How can I make the function read both ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing up one, not two arguments

```
"PrintElem('#services, #products')"
```

logging `console.log(elem1);` would show the string `"#services, #products"`

should be

```
"PrintElem('#services', '#products')"
```

Next issue is the fact that

```
Popup($(elem1, elem2).html());
```

is using elem2 as a context selector, it is not looking up the html of both elements. Your function is expecting two arguments so pass it both html strings

```
function PrintElem(elem1, elem2) {
  Popup($(elem1).html(), $(elem2).html());
}
```

Comment: Caught me as I was editing it @KJPrice :) Spotted that right after I made the answer for the first issue.